# c++ getstdhandle() background color

Tags: c++

I'm having a problem with my code. It's not a compiler error.

I have a function that, depending on a value, it changes the color when printing the cells of a 2D array. In my main, I have a for loop where I print over and over the same 2D array, and the values mentioned above don't change after every loop. Yet, after the 13th loop, the background messes up. I have uploaded an image of the execution window between loops 12 and 14. The following url is for the image.

[image]

The code is the following

```
void Planet::draw(){
int p=getHQ()->at(getHQ()->size()-1)->getPosHQX();
int q=getHQ()->at(getHQ()->size()-1)->getPosHQY();

HANDLE hConsole;
hConsole= GetStdHandle (STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
for (int i=0;i<BOO::getGlobalMapSize();i++){
    for (int j=0;j<BOO::getGlobalMapSize();j++){
        if (((i==p) && (j==q)) || ((i==p+1) && (j==q)) || ((i==p+2) && (j==q)) || ((i==p) && (j==q+1)) || ((i==p) && (j==q+2)) || ((i==p+1) && (j==q+2)) || ((i==p+2) && (j==q+1)) || ((i==p+2) && (j==q+2)) || ((i==p+1) && (j==q+1))){
            SetConsoleTextAttribute(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE),BACKGROUND_INTENSITY | BACKGROUND_RED | BACKGROUND_BLUE | BACKGROUND_GREEN);
        }
        else{
            if ((getZones()->at(i*BOO::getGlobalMapSize()+j)->getAccessDanger()>=0) && (getZones()->at(i*BOO::getGlobalMapSize()+j)->getAccessDanger()<0.3)){
                SetConsoleTextAttribute(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE),BACKGROUND_INTENSITY | BACKGROUND_GREEN);
            }
            else if ((getZones()->at(i*BOO::getGlobalMapSize()+j)->getAccessDanger()>=0.3) && (getZones()->at(i*BOO::getGlobalMapSize()+j)->getAccessDanger()<0.6)){
                SetConsoleTextAttribute(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE),BACKGROUND_INTENSITY | BACKGROUND_GREEN | BACKGROUND_RED);
            }
            else if ((getZones()->at(i*BOO::getGlobalMapSize()+j)->getAccessDanger()>=0.6) && (getZones()->at(i*BOO::getGlobalMapSize()+j)->getAccessDanger()<=1)){
                SetConsoleTextAttribute(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE),BACKGROUND_INTENSITY | BACKGROUND_RED);
            }
            else{
                SetConsoleTextAttribute(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE),BACKGROUND_INTENSITY | BACKGROUND_RED | BACKGROUND_BLUE | BACKGROUND_GREEN);
            }
        }
        cout<<getPlanet()->at(getPlanet()->size()-1)->Map[i][j];
        cout<<'|';
    }
    cout<<endl;
    SetConsoleTextAttribute(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE),BACKGROUND_INTENSITY | BACKGROUND_RED | BACKGROUND_BLUE | BACKGROUND_GREEN);
}
cout<<endl<<endl;
Sleep(500);
}

int main(){
srand(time(NULL));
Planet Zeus;
for (int ii=0;ii<14;ii++){
    Zeus.draw();
}
}
```

Comment: Restore the text attribute *before* cout<<endl;

Comment: Step through it in the debugger and see what the difference in logic is when the problem occurs.

Comment: Yes, it worked. I restored the text attribute as you said and now it's working as expected. Thank you a million times.